# How to create DBF field with length > 254?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, dbf

Is it possible to create a text field in a database (DBF) table with a length that is greater than 254 characters?

Using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No...check online for the specs for *.dbf files, they are well documented.  ArcGIS has no magic powers to extend the inherent limitations.  Consider a geodatabase instead.