# How to get text field to show > 254 characters?

Tags: fields-attributes

Is there away around the 254 character text field limit?

Comment: Again, which GIS software are you using? Good answers will depend on that information.

Comment: JoshJones, This may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50415/how-to-create-a-dbf-field-with-length-254.  Could you indicate whether or not that is the case (and if not, why not)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are referring to shapefile when you say

> 254 character text field limit

If so, you could create a feature class either in a personal (.mdb) or file (.gdb) geodatabase which can handle field/character text size larger than 254.